# Hide/Show a button based on info in a plist

Tags: ios, uibutton, plist, show-hide

I need an array in a plist which holds some null values (i.e. not every selection will have audio), which I've created as follows:

```
<dict>
<key>WalkingAudio</key>
  <array>
     <string>NULL</string>
     <string>classical.mp3</string>
     <string>NULL</string>
  </array>
```

I'm getting the information from the selection made like this:

```
//awakeFromNib
NSString *myPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *rootDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPlist];    
self.walkingAudio = [rootDictionary objectForKey:@"WalkingAudio"];

//didSlectItemAtIndex
walkingAudioChosen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.walkingAudio objectAtIndex:self.carousel.currentItemIndex]];
```

What I need is for a button to be visible on the next view controller only when there is audio available and remain hidden if no audio is available. What makes the most sense to me is an if-else statement in the prepareForSegue method as follows:

```
if (walkingAudio == NULL) {
        dvc.playButton.hidden=YES;
    } else {
        dvc.playButton.hidden=NO;
    }
```

But it always shows the button and plays part of the audio and then crashes. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array already contains strings, so replace:

```
walkingAudioChosen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.walkingAudio objectAtIndex:self.carousel.currentItemIndex]];
```

with

```
walkingAudioChosen = [self.walkingAudio objectAtIndex:self.carousel.currentItemIndex];
```

because the format doesn't do anything to help you.

Change the `if` statement to:

```
if ([walkingAudioChosen isEqualToString:@"NULL"]) {
```

because you want to compare the contents of 2 objects, not one pointer to NULL.

*(Corrected a typo in the `if` as well, need to compare the string, not the array)*

Comment: To add to @Wain example you can also get rid of the `if...else` by coding `dvc.playButton.hidden = ([walkingAudioChosen isEqualToString:@"NULL"]);`

Comment: Just changed my code to reflect your suggestions but I'm still having the same problem. I do have button effects (i.e. shadowing, etc) on the next view controller. Do I need to put those in conditionals as well maybe?

Comment: Got it! For anyone with the same problem, I used the if-else statement in the view controller where the button was located around the shadow-effects I had created for the button and it worked.  Both answers helped tremendously - thank you so much!